# How to avoid repetitive method calls?

Tags: ruby, capybara

I want to print some values from a HTML table using Capybara. My code looks like this:

```
area = find_by_id('SonDakika')

p area.all('tr')[0].text
p area.all('tr')[1].text
p area.all('tr')[2].text
# ...
p area.all('tr')[98].text
p area.all('tr')[99].text
p area.all('tr')[100].text
```

It works, but it's very long and repetitive. How can I shorten my code?

Comment: I have literally no idea what the question is about.

Comment: I think you are trying to extract values from a HTML table. Please show that table (your input) and your expected output. Which library are you using – Nokogiri? You are also talking about a form, what kind of form is that? And what does "139/5000" mean?

Comment: capybara @stefan

Comment: @Ferhat thanks, I've added a `capybara` tag. Could you clarify the other points, too?

Comment: @stefan Imagine a table is a hundred rows. I have to write a hundred prints using the method I wrote above. I just want a short and simple method with a print. English is not good I can not express myself fully I do not look up

Comment: So your above code works and you just want to remove the 100 repetitive calls? That's a basic loop: `0.upto(100) { |i| p area.all('tr')[i].text }`

Comment: If you want to print each row, you can also write: `area.all('tr').each { |row| p row.text }`

Comment: you are super thanks @Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop:

```
0.upto(100) { |i| p area.all('tr')[i].text }
```

Or – if you want to print every row – call `each`:

```
area.all('tr').each { |row| p row.text }
```